# Reason for Stack Overflow being down due to webcams?

Tags: discussion

Nick Craver mentioned this as the reason for [SO being down yesterday](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/836389959573651456)

> Nick_Craver: Load there was about a half million requests per minute (that actually got through). We're working on blocking compromised webcams now.

Any idea, what the above means and how come webcams took Stack Overflow down?

Comment: Hum, any source?

Comment: What Nick describes would be a DDOS attack using compromised network-connected security cameras.

Comment: @Tunaki: https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/836389959573651456

Comment: What @MartijnPieters said. We were (actually, still are) being attacked by a DDOS that is launched using security cameras.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: security cameras are really great for that => because people want live streaming, they usually have plenty of bandwidth to spare :/

Comment: Interestingly, Amazon Video, isitdownrightnow.com and downdetector.com amongst others weren't working yesterday at around 18:00 GMT+0

Comment: @WilliamIsted Amazon S3 was down.

Comment: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/03/01/aws_s3_outage/

Comment: @PatrickHofman completely missed that, thanks for the link! I wonder if this was caused by a IoT DDOS as well.

Comment: But why target StackOverflow? What have we done to them?

Comment: many reasons,some do just for revenge.You also don't need to be efficient in hacking to do this.There are hitman like services available:https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/09/israeli-online-attack-service-vdos-earned-600000-in-two-years/  .This was caught now

Comment: IoT is great: have all the PC programmers muck around with embedded systems, which they don't have a clue about. While at the same time have all the embedded programmers muck around with internet security, which they don't have a clue about. How can it possibly go wrong? But at least my fridge is connected to the internet now!

Comment: I love/hate the fact that so many random IoT devices now, when you boil them down, are just Linux webservers that are easy to get root on. Love it because it's hilarious and creates great stories, hate it because that's how stuff like this happens.

Comment: Hey, it could be worse. Amazon S3's Virginia center went down due to ["a mistyped command"](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/03/amazon-s3-problem-caused-by-command-line-mistake-during-maintenance/)...

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Black hat hackers have recently discovered the joyous existence of millions and millions of [IoT devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things), mostly routers and web cameras, that can be hacked and turned into a large DDOS botnet. Such networks are generally known by the malware that creates them, [Mirai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirai_(malware)).

Apparently such a Mirai botnet is now being used to DDOS Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow traffic spike during DDOS]

*(Source: https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/836404479054524419)*

See http://time.com/4542600/internet-outage-web-cams-hackers/ and https://www.wired.com/2016/10/internet-outage-webcam-dvr-botnet/ for some in-depth news reports on a recent high-profile DDOS attack on multiple internet services.

Comment: It's the start of machines testing the waters... Where are you John Connor!? :p

Comment: Required related reading on Twitter: https://twitter.com/internetofshit

Comment: Let's hope [this](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2016/09/27/the-invisible-war/) doesn't happen.

Comment: So in layman's terms, a huge number of basic internet-capable 'computer' devices are all trying to load stackoverflow.com at the same time?

Comment: Yes, basically. Maybe the devices are doing something more varied, like loading many different pages, or maybe they are focused on the front page. Either way they are overwhelming the site with bogus traffic.

Comment: @TylerH The Internet of Things basically. The Mirai open source botnet ([not kidding](https://arstechnica.com/security/2016/10/brace-yourselves-source-code-powering-potent-iot-ddoses-just-went-public/)) simply exploits devices with bad or no security and turns them into an army for DDOS purposes. Heck, [even your router might be doing it](https://arstechnica.com/staff/2017/02/router-assimilated-into-the-borg-sends-3tb-in-24-hours/). If it can phone home (goes through the firewall) and has a security hole, it's a security threat

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hat

Comment: Why do people do this? Morons. Smh.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, They are probably the people whose questions we downvoted and closed when they were first trying to figure out the site. I'm not saying we shouldn't, but I remember how frustrating it was.

Comment: In other words: DDoS Protection by CloudFlare is no protection? 180 Mbit/s isn't that much bandwidth.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: you know this is going through CloudFlare from that one picture alone?

Comment: @MartijnPieters isn't that the whole point of cloudflare? Are the real IP's revealed somewhere?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: Cloudflare can't operate without a public IP address to  proxy for. I don't know if that IP address was revealed or not, but we can't just jump to a conclusion that *DDoS Protection by CloudFlare is no protection*, or even that the bandwidth graph we see here is the full extend of the incoming attack.

Comment: @JonClements Don't joke about that! Yesterday was John Connor's birthday!

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I think it's 180 MBytes/s so it's over 1 Tbps

Comment: @Suragch: Heh, could be.

Comment: @Mas yep, MBps is megabytes per second, used to measure the amount of data flowing through. Mbps is megabits per second, to measure speed.

Comment: @Mas: Tbps? That seems to be off by a factor of 1000.

Comment: This attack might be the work of somebody who *really* didn't like the new Top Nav bar.  <grin>

Comment: @user2357112 yep, sorry I meant it in Gbps unit :)

Comment: I assume this is still ongoing?  I have not seen message indicating otherwise yet.

Answer (score 26):

In the 80s, cyberpunk dystopian fiction had hackers take over security cameras and use it to dodge the man, be able to slip unseen by them, and track people.

In the cyberpunk dystopian present, hackers take over security cameras to get them to solve complex mathematical problems on which there are bounties (using someone else's electricity)<sup>1</sup>, and use the cameras connection to the network to repeatedly yell "hello" to another computer in a way that makes the computer confused and clogs the network pipes.<sup>2</sup>

Truth is stranger than fiction.

If you need more details, I'll be back after I take my self driving electric car<sup>3</sup> for a drive to go for a ride on my hoverboard<sup>4</sup> while live-streaming it using a vanity flying self-piloted robot drone<sup>5</sup> which tracks my pocket supercomputer<sup>6</sup> to update my personal TV channel<sup>7</sup> which I earn beer money from; meanwhile, another robot will vacuum my floors<sup>8</sup>.

---

1. [Dogecoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogecoin)
2. [Mirai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirai_%28malware%29)
3. [Tesla](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iwfNs8j2FI)
4. [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/tp/hoverboard)
5. [Auto-tracking drones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zah81_H-3Jo)
6. [1980 supercomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_supercomputing#The_Cray_era:_mid-1970s_and_1980s)
7. [YouTube](https://youtube.com)
8. [Robot vacuum](http://cyberneticzoo.com/wp-content/uploads/file/rosie-the-robot-jetsons-vacuum.jpg)

Comment: (In b4 someone attempts to edit one of my own answers to change the footnote formatting to mirror what I did here.)